# Arguement of a complex number (is the original solution correct?)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

First time posting a question please bear with me.

Consider the complex number $$C = w+z = (k-4) + (1+5k)i$$

where $w = k + i$  and$ z = -4 + (5k)i$

this complex number (C) has an argument $2 \pi/3$

The question wants you to find k, here is the solution as follows:

[Original Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ki6O.png)

My problem is with how they dealt with the argument: $\tan(\frac{2π}{3})=-\sqrt{3}$ and the following equation  $-\sqrt{3} = \frac{1+5k}{k-4}$ (lines 3 & 4) and if the solution is indeed correct i would like to know where i am wrong, my trigonometry isn't the strongest.

i am under the impression that an argument of a complex number is the angle made between the **positive** x-axis (real axis) and the complex number (line C) on an argand diagram. so given that the $Arg (C) = 2\pi/3$, this angle is greater than $\pi/2$ (90 degress) and less than $\pi$ (180 degress) this would put the line C in the second quadrant (top left) of the real-imaginary axis. thus making it an obtuse angle

but to my knowledge this is not the same angle that is between line C and the **negative** x-axis (real axis) (or simply the pole of the real-axis that line C is closest too),
in which this angle would be between to the component line $k-4$ (adjacent) and opposite to component line ($1+5k$). where line C would be the hypotenuse of this triangle (modulus(C)).

So i became very confused when the solution used $\tan(\frac{2π}{3})=-\sqrt{3}$ and equated that to the $\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$ of the triangle made from line C and its 2 components $1+5k$ & $k-4$.

I understand that the opposite/adjacent of a triangle will be $\tan \theta$ ($\theta$ being the angle opposite to the hypotenuse) but this is angle should be the angle between line C and the negative axis and not the Arg(C) angle so i thought the solution would look like this instead

$Arg(C) = \pi - \theta = \frac{2π}{3}$

$θ = \frac{\pi}{3}$

$\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \sqrt{3}$

$\sqrt{3} = \frac{1+5k}{k-4}$

and through further manipulation

$k = \frac{-21\sqrt{3}-17}{22}$

Answer (score 1):

> I believe you are confusing [Reference Angle in the Unit Circle](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-four-quadrants.html) with [Argument (Angle in Polar Form)](https://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html) of a complex number.

Consider if $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$, then $\tan\dfrac{\pi}{3} = \dfrac{\sin{\dfrac{\pi}{3}}}{\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{3}}} = \dfrac{+}{+}$. We have $\Re{(C)} = r\cos\theta,\, r > 0$. Then,  $\operatorname{sgn}\left(\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{3}}\right) = +1 \implies \Re{(C)} > 0$

However, we know that $\Re{(C)} < 0$, since $C$ is in the second quadrant. This is a contradiction.